# Excel Script and Flow problem - Script not found. It may have been unshared or deleted. clientRequestId: ebf53c05-7f24-4537-a91d-9edb8903eb8c

Tags: sharepoint, scripting, powerapps

I have a PowerApp that takes a SharePoint list, filters the data, puts it in a collection, and calls a flow/PowerAutomate that formats the data and puts it in a CSV format. Then the flow creates a spreadsheet using a pre-configured spreadsheet as a template which has a script included. The script is shared:
[ExcelScriptProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10J3w.png)

When anyone but I run the flow either from the PowerApp or from the flow itself, they get an error "Script not found. It may have been unshared or deleted."  This happens when anyone other than me tries to run the app/flow. I've shared the app, the excel template file, the flow, and the script. I have the person who's helping me test listed as an owner on the SharePoint list. I've also tried recreating the script, the template, the flow, and even the app.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [sharepoint.se].