# Excel Script + Power Automate - Script not found. It may have been unshared or deleted

Tags: excel, powerapps, power-automate

I have a PowerApp that:

- takes a SharePoint file,
- filters the data,
- and calls a PowerApps/Flow to:

  - execute an Excel script,
  - get the file contents,
  - and create a file with it.

The script is shared to all PowerApps users, same for the source file, everyone can read, edit and delete the file.

When anyone but I run the flow either from the PowerApp or from the flow itself, they get an error "Script not found. It may have been unshared or deleted." This happens when anyone other than me tries to run the app/flow.

The weird thing is that if I run the PowerApps / Flow, everything works fine.

Do you know how can I get other users than me to run it either from the PowerApps or PowerAutomate ?

This issue is 'kinda' similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826415/excel-script-and-flow-problem-script-not-found-it-may-have-been-unshared-or-d) but it's different in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how this one is working. Sharing the solution here :

Firstly, you'll need to create all your flows and PowerApps apps within a "Solution". You can create a new solution from "Solutions/New solution".

Within this new solution, create a button-triggered flow that runs Office Scripts. Let's call it "Child flow". Please note this flow requires to have a last action to respond to a PowerApp or flow.

Configure this child flow with run-only users settings as described in my previous response. Make sure to choose "Use this connection ...".

Within the same solution, create another flow with the PowerApps trigger. This flow will be triggered by your PowerApps app. In this flow, add a step to run the child flow you've just created above.

Within the same solution, create your PowerApps app. Configure your PowerApps button to run the second flow (the parent flow).

Now share the PowerApps app with another user, ask them to try it out, and see if the Run script action in the child flow can work properly.

Thanks to Yutao from MS for [the solution](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Office-Script-Error-quot-Script-not-found-It-may-have-been/td-p/759283) !